# High CPU usage on PI on kaa client start

Tags: kaa

When I start the KAA client SDK ( JAVA ) on a raspberry PI the CPU usage shoots up to 100%. As soon as I kill the process the CPU usage drops back to normal

Below is the code snippet using to start the kaa where i am starting the kaa client on a raspberry pi

```
public class NotificationSystemTestApp {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotificationSystemTestApp.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        /*System.out.println(encryptString("abcd", "12332sd1133sdssd45"));
        return;*/
        new NotificationSystemTestApp().launch();
    }

    private void launch() throws InterruptedException {
        // Create client for Kaa SDK

        final KaaClient kaaClient;
        DesktopKaaPlatformContext desktopKaaPlatformContext = new DesktopKaaPlatformContext();
        final CountDownLatch startupLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        kaaClient = Kaa.newClient(desktopKaaPlatformContext, new SimpleKaaClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStarted() {
                LOG.info("--= Kaa client started =--");
                startupLatch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopped() {
                LOG.info("--= Kaa client stopped =--");
            }
        }, true);

        kaaClient.setProfileContainer(new ProfileContainer() {
            public ClientProfile getProfile() {
                return new ClientProfile() {{
                    setClientProfileInfo(new ProfileInfo() {{
                        setRidlrId("R_00001");
                        setStationName("Mumbai");
                        setEquipmentId("EQ0006");
                        setStationId("5");
                    }});
                }};
            }
        });
        // Registering listener for topic updates

        kaaClient.start();
        startupLatch.await();

        kaaClient.addTopicListListener(new NotificationTopicListListener() {
            public void onListUpdated(List<Topic> topicList) {
                System.out.println("Topic list updated!");
                for (Topic topic : topicList) {
                    LOG.info("Received topic with id {} and name {}", topic.getId(), topic.getName());
                }
            }
        });

        final ScanInfo scanInfo = new ScanInfo() {{
            setDestinationId("12");
            setSourceId("3");
            setEquipmentId("R_00001");
            setScanTime(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            setEvent("ENTRY");
            setTransactionId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }};

        kaaClient.attachEndpoint(new EndpointAccessToken("1234"), new OnAttachEndpointOperationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAttach(SyncResponseResultType result, EndpointKeyHash resultContext) {

            }
        });
        kaaClient.attachUser("user1", "1234", new UserAttachCallback() {
            public void onAttachResult(UserAttachResponse response) {
                System.out.println("Attach User Success - " + response.getResult());
            }
        });


        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOG.error("FATA", e);
        }


        LOG.debug("End Point key hash - " + kaaClient.getEndpointKeyHash());
        while (true) {
            kaaClient.addLogRecord(new LoggerSchema() {{
                setData("");
                setMessageType("");
            }});
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Rizwan

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you use constant addition of log records for upload to the Kaa server. The delay is just 10 milliseconds which might be too short for the Raspberry PI system you are running the application on.

Depending on the configuration, the Kaa Client might add considerable processing overhead for each log record with processing in other Java threads causing CPU to constantly spin adding and processing new records.

Try increasing the delay in your 'while (true)' loop and check the CPU usage with different log upload settings.

Should this information be not enough for you to fix the issue, please add  logs from the Kaa client and Kaa server for investigation.